# Webapi oauth accestoken invalid expiration date

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, oauth, bearer-token

We are building a frontend application that is making extensive use of an webapi backend. 
In this application we are using oauth to log a user in and store all of the claims that belong to that user inside off access tokens.
On the frontend we are using sentry error logging (http://www.getsentry.com) to log all of our javascript errors. This includes any webapi calls that somehow went wrong or do not return the result we are expecting. With every error we recieve we also log the cookie information along with it, which includes the access tokens that that specific user was using at that time.

Right now we are seeing alot of webapi calls that went wrong because the calls they made are forbidden. I checked some of their access tokens and immeadiately i noticed that the information was way out of date and should have been refreshed a long time ago because the access token should have expired already.

By using :

```cs
 var ticket = Startup.OAuthOptions.AccessTokenFormat.Unprotect("tokenhere");
```

on my localhost machine inside the debugger i can unprotect the access tokens and view the information inside of them.

Like i said the information inside some of these tokens contains invalid information and should have been refreshed already..
Then i noticed that the reason they are not refreshed yet is because the ExpiresUtc is more than 2 years bigger than the IssuedUtc. In other words; The token wont expire until after 2 years.

Here is some example information of one of these tokens

```cs
IssuedUtc: { 20/02/2016 03:04:40 +00:00}
ExpiresUtc: {16/11/2018 03:04:40 +00:00}
```

We are using the default expire time from oauth (20 minutes) and somehow in the pipeline it is setting it to be bigger than 2 years. The only way a user can now refresh their claims is if he logs out and back in again, and obviously until they do so it is creating alot of errors on the frontend side.
By debugging my own tokens i can verify that it is setting it to 20 minutes and have never managed to reproduce it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, we had an controller method hidden somewhere that was issueing access tokens with an expiry date of 2 years.. Doh